# Flexboxgrid.css does not center the navigation tab

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, flexbox

I am following a tutorial about RoR and they use the flexbox grid layout to give style to the pages.

I have the error that the flexbox is not centering my navigation tab as it should be done.

I have at the moment 4 different tabs in the navigation bar plus a title. Like this: Title  A  B  C  D

Flexbox should divide the 100% of the screen width into 5 to give the correct spacing to each tab, but it does not do it and all stays at the middle of the screen.

That is why I would appreciate any help. What I am doing wrong?

I saved `flexboxgrid.css` in `assets/stylesheets`.

My `application.html.erb` is:

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Blog</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="be-red white large-padding">
            <ul class="no-list row center-xs middle-xs">
                <li class="col-md" >
                    <h1 class="no-margin" id="logo">Blog Facilito</h1>
                </li>
                <li class="col-md">
                    <%= link_to "Inicio", root_path %>
                </li>
                <li class="col-md">
                    Diseno      
                </li>
                <li class="col-md">
                    Programacion
                </li>
                <li class="col-md">
                    Tecnologia
                </li>

            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

`Style.css` is:

```
*{
    margin: 0px;
}

a,a:visited{
    color: inherit !important;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#logo{
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.no-margin{
    margin: 0px;
}

.be-red{
    background-color: rgb(200,50,50);
}

.large-padding{
    padding: 10px 7px;
}

.white{
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uriel use different version of flex-box grid he uses version 6.1.1 and you are using I guest the newest version.

try this put this after the title. at application.HTML.erb .

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/flexboxgrid/6.1.1/flexboxgrid.min.css" type="text/css" />`

or download the flexbox grid 6.1.1 from here :

https://github.com/kristoferjoseph/flexboxgrid.

hope you understand my bad english .

Answer (score 2):

I don't know ruby-on-rails, which seems to add its own css library, but you can try

```
.row {
  display: flex;      /* Magic begins */
}
.col-md {
  flex: 1;            /* Distribute widths equally */
  text-align: center; /* Center inner text */
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0;
}
a, a:visited {
  color: inherit !important;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#logo {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
.no-margin {
  margin: 0px;
}
.be-red {
  background-color: rgb(200, 50, 50);
}
.large-padding {
  padding: 10px 7px;
}
.white {
  color: white;
}
.no-list {
  list-style: none;
}
.row {
  display: flex;      /* Magic begins */
}
.col-md {
  flex: 1;            /* Distribute widths equally */
  text-align: center; /* Center inner text */
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="be-red white large-padding">
    <ul class="no-list row center-xs middle-xs">
      <li class="col-md" >
        <h1 class="no-margin" id="logo">Blog Facilito</h1>
      </li>
      <li class="col-md">Inicio</li>
      <li class="col-md">Diseno </li>
      <li class="col-md">Programacion</li>
      <li class="col-md">Tecnologia</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Your suggestion works perfectly, but now I wonder why it does not load the flexboxgrid.css from the folder. I shouldn't actually add new css styles to my stylesheet style.css.